# Textarea data not being sent via POST on PHPMailer

Tags: php, post, textarea, phpmailer

I have a form on my website that is working apart from the textarea data not being sent in the email. The form lets people enter name, email and a message. I receive the email and I get the name and email, but the "message" area is blank.

I have even tried to change the textarea to an input field but not even this is sent in the email? I have no idea why this is not working. Can anyone please help.

Below is HTML form code as well as PHP mail.

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="php/mail.php" name="cform" id="cform">
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" placeholder="Your name..." >
    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 noMarr" placeholder="Your email..." >
    <textarea name="message" id="message" type="text" cols="40" rows="5" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="send" class="submitBnt" value="Send Message">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?
    require("class.phpmailer.php");

    // form validation vars
    $formok = true;
    $errors = array();

    // sumbission data
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $date = date('d/m/Y');
    $time = date('H:i:s');

    // form data
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP - mail or smtp.domain.com
    $mail->Host     = "myserver"; // SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "myUsername"; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = "myPassword"; // SMTP password
    $mail->From     = "myEmail@Address.com"; // SMTP username
    $mail->AddAddress("myEmail@Address.com"); // Your Adress
    $mail->Subject  =  "New contact request from My Website !";
    $mail->IsHTML(true);  
    $mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Body     = "<p>You have recieved a new message from the enquiries form on your website.</p>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Name: </strong>{$name} 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Email Address: </strong>{$email} 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Message: </strong>{$message} // NOT WORKING HERE
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}
                        </p>";

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
       echo "There was an error... unable to send email <p>";
       echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }

    echo "Thank you. Your email has been sent.";
?>
```

Comment: I've run that code locally and it works fine. Are you using any javascript on the form? Check the message field is being sent to the server by using print_r($_POST) in your php script.

Comment: Nope not running any Javascript on the form. What is posted in the question is what I have. Will try print_r() quickly...

Comment: No this is the output from the print_r() - Array ( [name] => sfdfg xdf sdf gsdfsg f [email] => fdsgsdff@dfkgjdf.com ) Thank you. Your email has been sent.

Comment: Hmm very strange. Are you sure you don't have any javascript on the page that could be interfering? Maybe bootstrap or another front end framework? Just out of curiosity what happens when you change the field name to something other than message? Does it appear in the print_r this time?

Comment: Yes have Javascript (Bootstrap) running on the page but dont know will that interfere with just my message field?. I have also tried to change the field to "mymessage" and I have also changed the textarea to an "input" and changed the field name to "mymessage" on input as well - but again nothing is sent. I am completely stumped. Dont know why only 2 fields are sent but not the 3rd.

Comment: Just to rule out a javascript issue can you disable javascript in your browser and give it another go. Also what browser are you using? The type="text" attribute isn't needed for textareas but doubt that would make a difference.

Comment: Also enctype="multipart/form-data" isn't needed for forms unless you are uploading files so try removing that.

Comment: Removed enctype="multipart/form-data" and still no content. But when I disabled Javascript - success! I get the message content. How do I now track down what Javascript is causing this issue?

Comment: If you are using Chrome check the console section of the developer toolbar (Ctrl + Shift +I) after you have submitted the form. You might need to click the "Preserve Log" option if you are not submitting via ajax.

Comment: Thanks @dk80. Can now work with list of errors. If you want to create the answer as the Javascript being the issue I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 'message' post parameter is not being received on the server this is a being cleared on the front end. This is probably being caused by javascript validation of the form or any WYSIWYG used to edit the field.